# How to understand the instant state collapse in all references?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

When a subsystem A of an EPR pair AB is measured, it's usually said that the state of B collapse instantly, and also this is true for all observers according to relativistic quantum information.

Since different observers have different time lines, if A, B are spacelike located, the only possible explain for the 'instant collapse in all references' is that AB still occupies the same spacetime point.

Are there any work or evidence on this? Considering the current idea of the close relationship between entanglement and spacetime construction, is this possible?

Comment: I would say that you just gave a very good reason why one should not talk about "collapse" as a physical phenomenon. The only testable physics happens during the interactions of the observers with the quantum system and the causality of those is described perfectly by special relativity. To speculate what happens at any other time without disturbing the system is simply not a testable hypothesis.

Comment: @CuriousOne If no collapse, then what's the state of B after the measurement of A? A proper mixture or something else? I am currently considering the closed timelike curve based quantum information processing, and the measurement on EPR is the core problem. Do you have any suggestion on the possible output of the measurement?

Comment: The physical "state of B" is nothing until it has been measured, we simply happen to know already at A what the correlation between the two measurements will be. So do we know instantaneously at A what we will be getting from B after a while? Yes. That's because the measurement at A and the correlation that depends on A are evaluated at the same coordinate. The situation is simply not symmetric in that B can't know this until it has gotten a message from A. B will always measure a random outcome and it will learn about the correlation later, which is perfectly in line with relativity.

Comment: possible duplicate http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23163/solution-to-the-quantum-measurement-problem

Comment: @CuriousOne Thanks. Let's leave the 'collapse' concept, but just think the correlation of the measurement results of A,B. Experiments show the correlation does exist non-locally, in the case that the events of A and B's measurements are spacelike separated. I am wondering can such a thing regarded 'superluminal'? Or the entanglement itself plays a role in the spacetime structure so that our traditional concept of 'local' should be re-examined?

Comment: @CuriousOne I am asking this question because there are some results on designing 'superluminal signalling' system with a nonlinear extension of QM based on CTC. But there they always assume that after the measurement of subsystem A of an EPR pair AB, B can be described as a proper mixture. I do not agree with this. Are there any other possibilities? Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely nothing detectable happens at B during the "collapse". The only way it can be "detected" is by making a correlation with the measurement at A, which means that A and B know it at different times. Since there is nothing even remotely resembling a universal time, this doesn't translate into a violation of relativity. If you are sending a message to Mars, you know the content of it here, right now, but Mars will only know it in e.g. 20 minutes. This is no different.

Comment: Nothing even remotely resembling a superluminal device can be constructed this way. All quantum cryptography devices require two links, one quantum, the other ordinary. The second, non-quantum link always "obeys" relativity and the quantum link alone doesn't convey any information on its own.

Comment: @CuriousOne Thanks. But the Aspect-like experiment does verify that non-local correlation between EPR pairs. This at least means that the nonlocal-signaling happens. At least when nonlinear QM is assumed, this can be used to construct a nonlocal signaling device. Of course since it does not involve anything 'solid' to carry the information, so it might not violate relativity.

Comment: Non-local signaling is simply a misinterpretation of time-like correlations that are not "signaling". It's not that much different from a similar misinterpretation of faster than light phase velocities. Look, you can assume any model you like in physics, if nature doesn't care about it (and nature doesn't seem to care about non-linear QM), then it's just a false model. The day you can transmit one bit of information faster than light in an experiment you will have a new theory, but until then you have nothing but a misunderstanding about how nature works.